# what does forward slash do in this django settings.py python list?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and I don't understand how this forward slash works in the django settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

It seems like it is concatenating the value of BASE_DIR + "static", but that would actually be str(BASE_DIR) + "static" correct?

Is it a special Django delimiter of sometype?

This is the correct usage according to the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

STATICFILES_DIRS Is not a parameter list - so this doesn't seem to apply
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-does-the-slash-in-the-parameter-list-of-a-function-mean

It's not a binary division operator:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably `BASE_DIR` is a [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object. The `/` is the path component concatenation operator.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> BASE_DIR = Path('/tmp')
>>> BASE_DIR / 'foo' / 'bar'
PosixPath('/tmp/foo/bar')
>>> str(BASE_DIR / 'foo' / 'bar')
'/tmp/foo/bar'
```

Comment: Thanks!  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators -- that was it!

Answer (score 0):

By default  BASE_DIR  would be set from Django 3.1  to ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl#L16)):

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

`/` does the same as  os.path.join() ( pathlib is new module introduced in python 3.4) as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators)

> The slash operator helps create child paths, similarly to
> os.path.join()

For example

```
BASE_DIR = Path('/base')
print(BASE_DIR / 'static')
```

would result in /base/static